# Oracle SQL to get Unique Records

Tags: sql, oracle

Does anyone know the sql to pull 4 rows from the following table which contains 8 rows?
Just want one row for each arbitrary person.
The real data will be thousands of records so it must be generic and use only the ID's not the names.

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPbtz.png)

Comment: To improve the quality of your question firstly include your table as text in the question rather than as a link to an image.  This makes reviewing your information quicker by keeping all of your information in one place.  Links to images are good for when you need to show information that can not be readily reproduced in your Question, such as diagrams, graphical output, etc.  Secondly, please expand on what you mean by "each arbitrary person".  Thirdly, complement your table of sample data with a table showing the desired output.

Comment: Thanks, Arbitrary meaning It does'nt matter to me who appears first or second in the result set. I tried to post text but it rendered in a very unreadable way so I deleted it and posted the image. I'll have to get used to this system and try again next time. I would most likely post the sample table creation script and sample row inserts to make it easier.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a symmetric relationship.  So, you can do:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id < t.pid;
```

Comment: I used this method. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    ID, 
    FName,
    LName
  from your_table
union
select
    PID,
    PFName,
    PLName
  from your_table
order by 3, 2, 1
```